# Perform node-mysql queries in a highland stream

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, stream, node-mysql, highland.js

I have to pump lines from an input file, transform them and put them in an output file.

Since, the input file is huge, I stream it thanks to HighlandJS.

Transformation step includes async queries in MySQL DB (via node-mysql) and
I can't find out how to manage async queries in a stream. My different tries gives errors or nothing.

My last try is that:

```
h(inputStream)
.split()
.through(JSONStream.parse())
.map(function (data) {
    h.wrapCallback(pool.query(data, function (err, rows) {
        return rows;
    }));
})
.pipe(outputStream);
```

Any hints on how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Your `map` transformation has to return something. Right now it returns nothing.

Long answer:

Ok, I'm going to slightly simplify your logic for the purpouses of this answer. Let's say we want this.

```
input -> map to rows -> output
```

The problem is that the mapping is async, as you've poited out, and the `map` function has to return something. In this case, you just return a stream for each element in the input. So it looks like this.

```
// input -> map to a stream of streams of rows -> output
h(input).map(h.wrapCallback(pool.query)).pipe(output);
```

The last problem is actually getting rows instead of a stream of streams. You can do this by using the `flatMap` transformation, which will "flatten" the stream of streams to a "normal" stream.

```
// input -> map to a stream of rows -> output
h(input).flatMap(h.wrapCallback(pool.query)).pipe(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It almost made it!
But I gave me this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'connectionConfig' of undefined`

I think this is a context binding issue when wrapping `pool.query` inside `h.wrapCallback`.

Is there something specific to do to keep the context intact?

Comment: Try `pool.query.bind(pool)`.